# Branch.io returns me a File Not Found

Tags: deep-linking, branch.io, deeplink

I'm trying the Branch.io API and I think I'm getting a weird problem because I'm not able to create my links properly: I can use the link for starting the app without parameter: this link http://4t3i.app.link/KDSYTMnSZs.

It works perfectly but as soon as I try to put some parameter following the [doc](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/creating-links-other-ways/guide/#appending-query-parameters) for appending query parameters, it returns a `File Not Found` Webpage.

[image: FNF]

I tried:

- https://4t3i.app.link/a/?&jobId=saucisse
- https://4t3i.app.link/a?%24deeplink_path=article%2Fjan%2F123&%24fallback_url=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com&channel=facebook&feature=affiliate&user_id=4562&name=Alex (that's the example they give)

I have the feeling I'm really missing something but no idea what. Is that so easy to add parameters: just a/ and then appending parameters??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alex from Branch.io here:

We recently made a major back-end change to accommodate some new technical limitations that Apple imposed with iOS 9.3.1, and unfortunately it looks like we didn't fully update all our docs yet!

Your links are correct, but the `/a` is no longer necessary. So they would be:

- https://4t3i.app.link?&jobId=saucisse
- https://4t3i.app.link?%24deeplink_path=article%2Fjan%2F123&%24fallback_url=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com&channel=facebook&feature=affiliate&user_id=4562&name=Alex

When you open these, you'll be able to see the link clicks coming through on [this dashboard page](https://dashboard.branch.io/#/liveview/link_clicks/view)

Thanks for noticing this. I'll make sure we get the documentation changedto reflect the new system.

**Edit:** also note that those examples above create *new* links with the specified parameters. If you simply want to append an additional parameter to an existing link, you'd do this: http://4t3i.app.link/KDSYTMnSZs?jobId=saucisse

Comment: That's what I call a support! Saturday, no worries, we still answer mails and SO. GG Branch Metrics

Comment: Glad we could get it sorted out for you — we love our partners! :)

Comment: Hello, @AlexBauer! BranchIO link with custom domain returns me a "File Not Found". However I cant see any /a in the link. It is completely generated by Branch.IO - http://branchiotest3.app.link/IvSjbtB96u Could you, please, advice. Thanks!

Comment: @JastinBall, this is fascinating — you've found a bug in our dashboard UX! The domain assigned to your app was `hat3.app.link`, and that **Custom domain name** box is actually intended for non-app.link domains. What you've done here is totally logical, but actually not supported. Could you [send in a ticket](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new) so we can get this sorted out for you?